# Why when I publish the project in Actionscript my screen does not visualize the content?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I've been the whole day looking for the error for this situation and I've not found an answer... I just started with AS (and with every the programming staff in general), sorry if this is a dump question, but I can't understand this:

I have an empty workflow. I've created a movieclip with 3 frames each of them with one label.

I've created then 3 arrays, 1 for the labels, and 2 for the position of the objects.

I publish the project and there is no errors, but I can visualize only the first addChild in the screen. 
Here is the code:

```
var Piece:piece = new piece;

var Piece_type:Array = [
                                  "tS",  "tD", "tC"];

var  X: Array = [25,55,85];
var  Y: Array = [221,221,221];



PrintBoard();

function PrintBoard():void
{

    for(var i:int = 0; i < Piece_type.length; i++)
    {
        addChild(Piece);

        Piece.x = X[i];
        Piece.y = Y[i];
        Piece.label = Piece_type[i];
        trace("why?");
    }
}
```

There is no errors in the console and the loop is finishing with 3 walk throughs, but only with 1 object. I am using Actionscript 3 and the publishing setting are for Air 3.2 Android

If anyone knows what's going on it would be really helpful... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an `instance` of the class:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < Piece_type.length; i++)
 {
    var myPiece:Piece = new Piece;
    addChild(myPiece);

    myPiece.x = X[i];
    myPiece.y = Y[i];
    myPiece.label = myPiece_type[i];
    trace("why?");
 }
```

Also, it is not a good idea to name things the same as actionscript keywords or properties – like naming your array "X" - may do no harm in some cases but can lead to confusing bugs in others.